# Can't mount USB : "Not Authorized"

Tags: mount, usb-drive

Since three months I am waiting and searching for a solution to mount a USB stick again.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 32bit and 64bit  Dell machines and I could not really find a useful answer what exactly I need to do being able to mount a USB Stick.

```
Unable to mount [VolumeName] Not authorized
```

Can you please point me in the right direction what I need to do/change/adjust being able to mount a USB device again?

Comment: This happened to me when I added a nopasswd user.  When I removed that user the problem went away.

Comment: Can you mount it as root (sudo mount /dev/disk/by-label/whatever /media/wherever)?

Comment: @ohno I have the same problem, and I can only mount my exFAT USB as root. Is there way to make it able to be mounted without root privileges or at least prompt me for an admin password?

Answer (score 6):

I think this could be the answer here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

It says: "If your usb device doesn't appear on your desktop, you should check that your user has the correct privileges. Go to System->Administration->User and Groups, choose the user, click on "Properties", then go to the "User Privileges" tab. You should have the "Access external storage devices automatically" option checked."

Comment: there's no longer a "Properties" option to click on, nor a "User Privileges" tab.

Answer (score 6):

In terminal, type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The command output will show different devices; among them, you will find the one you want to mount. For instance, if it is /dev/sdb1, of type ntfs, you will want to type:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/your-username/ext-drive-folder/
```

Where the folder /media/your-username/ext-drive-folder/ is a folder you created for the external drive to be mounted in.

This would be annoying to do every time you want to mount an external device, but, "in case of emergency", it can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

In gentoo, I had to edit the polkit rule /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy
and change the rule
change allow_any rule to:
      yes

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 when trying to mount a kindle automatically. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If your USB stick is formatted ntfs make sure you have the NTFS Fuse programs installed.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs;
```

Comment: ntfs-3g ntfsprogs programs are uncompatible. ntfsprogs is deprecated. go with ntfs-3f.

Answer (score 0):

@ohno's comment from earlier worked in mounting an off-brand mp3 player on 16.04 crouton

```
sudo mount /dev/disk/by-label/device_name /media/directory_name
```

quick and easy