# Cannot mount partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, permissions, unmount

I am unable to mount my two of the partitions (NTFS) currently. When I double click on it from the file manager, a pop up window says

> unable to access {disk lable}. Not authorized to perform operation.

I used to be able to mount them and access the files earlier. I recently played with the file permissions recently (from the dive properties), but don't remember changing it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I know it's for USB, but try the first answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120147/cant-mount-usb-not-authorized

Comment: It's not USB.. I am unable to mount partitions from my internal HDD in which Ubuntu itself is installed.

Comment: I'm not saying yours is, I'm saying the thread linked to is.

Comment: Oh sorry.. But it doesn't help...

I think my user id has been stripped off its root access. I can't do anything on the GUI interface, can't update (only partial update allowed), can't add or delete users etc...

Comment: I doubt it. Does your account log in automatically, or does it not have a password. Either of these things could be the problem,

Comment: My account automatically logs in.. and it has a password too.. However I have set the account to auto log in at start up (without password prompt).

Comment: Set it to not automatically log in.

Comment: And then reboot.

Comment: I can't change it.. The button simply doesn't move.. It's not active.. Is there a way I can do it in the terminal?

Comment: You need to click the "Unlock" button in the top right corner of the window.

Comment: Can't click on that too.. it is simply not active...

Comment: Reboot and then try.

Comment: Nevermind about rebooting. Try this command instead and then log out and back in: `sudo usermod -a -G sudo [username]`.

Comment: I replaced `[username]` with my username, and this is what I get
`usermod: user '[FOX32]' does not exist`

Comment: Don't put the brackets around it.

Comment: Sorry, Newbie with terminals.... Still I get this
`usermod: user 'FOX32' does not exist`

Comment: Is your username all caps?

Comment: That's correct.. all caps...
The entire code:
`fox32@FOXBOOK:~$ sudo usermod -a -G sudo FOX32`

`[sudo] password for fox32: `

`usermod: user 'FOX32' does not exist`

`fox32@FOXBOOK:`

Comment: Sorry for being so persistent, but have you checked that in User Accounts?

Comment: Yes, in user accounts window, on the panel, as well as on the power button drop down.. it's FOX32.. all caps

However in user accounts, I see that FOX32 is what's mentioned and below that its fox32 as well

Comment: I tried with fox32 and the error doesn't show now... BINGO... 

Still I can't click on the `unlock` button on the top right corner or change the automatic log in to off.

Comment: OK. Try mounting the drive.

Comment: Tried mounting.. same error...

Comment: Wait, sorry. Log out and then back in.

Comment: Another strange thing is, when my system is locked, the ubuntu version written in the wallpaper is 14.10. I had never upgraded to this version. the about this computer window shows the correct version: 14.04.

Is there any problem?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Perhaps I should reinstall or repair using a live usb

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have a repair feature, and the reinstall doesn't work for huge system problems.

Comment: please help us help you by [editing] your question and adding the output of `groups fox32`